# Stop Exit on Back Button Android in PhoneGap - Build

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building my application through **PhoneGap Build** online.
I want to change the default behavior of Back Button

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
});

function onBackKeyDown(){
    alert('back');
    return false;
}
```

Its not working I've searched for solution. But, they all showing to change the **java** codes in PhoneGap library, which is not in my case. I'm submitting my application in a *.zip* format with *config.xml* inside.

Is it possible with *config.xml*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all I did wrong as pointed by @Mejo, Thanks. Here is the solution to the problem.

**Step 1:** Include Script to HTML don't need it physically within application zip, as included *automatically by PhoneGap Build*

`<script src="cordova.js"></script>` or `<script src="phonegap.js"></script>` any of them will work fine.

**Step 2:** Add this to script to get **device ready** call:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

**Step 3:** Add *event listener* to **back button** and add your code to that call:

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
function onBackKeyDown(){
    alert('back');
    return false;
}
```

Still now it will not work if you don't set preference of **minSDK** to application by *config.xml*

**Step 4:** Add this to preference region of *config.xml*

`<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="5" />`

For reference: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how_to_handle_back_button_in_android

Answer (score 3):

Its said in Cordova API documentation that

> Typically, you will want to attach an event listener with
>   document.addEventListener **once you receive the PhoneGap 'deviceready'
>   event.**

So change your code like this

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
function onBackKeyDown() {
         //Your backbutton code
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mejo for your reply actually there is another thing which I'm going to post the answer.