# cordova return to app from external page

Tags: android, cordova, google-maps-api-3

My Crodova Android app uses Google maps API V3. As this is a standard google map user can click on POI for more info. or open "Terms Of Use" that takes user to external page still displayed in app. 
Because I have overriden `backButton` event with my own function, app is stuck on that external page.

abridged my onBackButton function:

```
if (notificationWindowOpen()){
        closeNotificationWindow();
    }
else{
    if (currentPage === document.getElementById('page1')){
            navigator.app.exitApp();     
    }
    else{
    showPage('page1');
    }
}
```

If I unbind `backButton` from my own `onBackButton` function, app can get out of external view.
While app is displaying external page, it looks like my `onBackButton` function is not executed at all.

Comment: Have you `add event listener to back button and add your code to that call` ? Also check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14208893) for the whole steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inAppBrowser plugin to open the "Terms of Use", just prevent the navigation inside your webview and use window.open with _blank param, like this:

```
$('#map_canvas').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
});
```