# Android back button to work with navigation in PhoneGap app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, onsen-ui

I'm building a PhoneGap mobile app with Onsen UI on the top.

I want the basic android back button to work with the onsen navigator and ons-sliding-menu, so it does what it's supposed to do.

I don't want it to close the app.

To prevent the back button from closing the app, I used the following code in the index.js files onDeviceReady event:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

What changes should I make, for the back button to work properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop Exit on Back Button Android in PhoneGap - Build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207690/stop-exit-on-back-button-android-in-phonegap-build)

Comment: Well actually what you did seems sufficient to me. Onsen UI should have default listeners for the `sliding-menu` and `navigator`, so since you aren't disabling them in any way (only preventing the default behaviour which is closing the app) it should be fine as it is. If you run into any problems later you can ask for help, but right now it looks like this should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [Documentation](https://onsen.io/v1/reference/ons-navigator.html) I found that to control navigation you could use the pushPage and popPage functions.

So maybe try something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    yourNavigator.popPage('page.html');
}
```