# Cordova backbutton not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have a problem that Cordova event on the Back button does not do anything yet to execute alert ("").

It is interesting that the code looks like it's perfectly fine and I did not even forget to introduce `cordova.js` the only thing I can think is that it is necessary to wash a plug-in, Because I do not have any established.

**My code looks like this:**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/phonon.css" />
    <style>
        .uvitani {
            font-size: 250%;
            margin: 0;
            color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 40%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-right: -50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
        }

        .tlacitko {
            margin: 0;
            color: #0084e7;
            background-color: white;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 50%;
            margin-right: -50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
        }
    </style>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function barva() {
        alert(cordova.platformId);
        if (cordova.platformId == 'android') {
            StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#0065b3");
        }
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

        function onBackKeyDown() {
            alert("Back");
        }
    }
</script>

<body style="background-color: #0084e7;" onload="barva();">
    <center>
        <p class="uvitani">Vítejte v aplikaci ISAS</p>
        <button class="btn tlacitko" onclick='document.location="styl.html";'>Pokračovat</button>
    </center>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/phonon-core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/components/forms.js"></script>
    <script src="js/components/preloaders.js"></script>
    <script src="js/components/dialogs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add the error to your question

Comment: please passed some characters in alert like alert("back");

Comment: please return false from function and write your back event function outside

Comment: please check solution

Comment: Still does not work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please passed some characters in alert box and return to false,

```
      function barva() {
          alert(cordova.platformId);
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
       }

      function onDeviceReady(){
        if (cordova.platformId == 'android') {
              StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#0065b3");
           }
          document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
      }
      function onBackKeyDown(){
          alert('back');
          return false;
      }
```

for more help check to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207690/stop-exit-on-back-button-android-in-phonegap-build).

please check your plugin ,

you need to add following plugin in your project

```
   cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar
```

Hopes this will help you !!!

Comment: please comment the code for some time check solution

Answer (score 0):

It was enough to fix statusbar color ( `I/chromium(18807): [INFO:CONSOLE(37)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: StatusBar is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/login.html (37)` ) and now it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function barva() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    function onDeviceReady() {
        if (cordova.platformId == 'android') {
            StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#0065b3");
        }
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }
    function onBackKeyDown() {
        alert("back");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Thank you for your help.